Заменить текст в docx документе без шаблонных символов
Просмотрел такие библиотеки как docx и docx-templates. И там и там текст обязательно должен быть заключен в скобки (в docx {{текст}}). В docx-templates следующий код выдает ошибку:
import { createReport } from 'docx-templates'

const response = await fetch(documentLink)
if (!response.ok) {
  throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`)
}
const documentBuffer = Buffer.from(await response.arrayBuffer())
const replacements = replacementTexts.reduce(
  (acc: Record<string, string>, replacementText) => {
    acc[replacementText.origin.replace(/{{(.*?)}}/g, '$1')] = replacementText.replacement
    return acc
  },
  {},
)
const report = await createReport({
    template: documentBuffer,
    data: replacements,
    cmdDelimiter: ['', ''], <----- Ошибка
  })

Есть ли библиотека node.js (типизированная), позволяющая делать это без явного указания шаблона?
